# Conditional expression to convert figure to table. Is it possible?

Tags: tables, graphics, pdf, conditionals, markdown

**I have a though one for you:**
I'm writing in MultiMarkdown and all my figures, tables, charts are usually pictures. This allows me to write something like this:

#### The MultiMarkdown input

```
![This is the caption.][table1]

[table_sometable]: tab_pic1.png
```

… and end up with:

#### Compiled LaTeX

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=\textwidth,height=0.75\textheight]{tab_pic1.png}
\caption{This is the caption.}
\label{table_sometable}
\end{figure}
```

I thought about writing a shell script that simple exchanges `\begin{figure}` to `\begin{table}` (same for `\end{figure}`) before I compile my *.tex* file with *pdflatex* to a PDF.

However, I'm looking for a pure LaTeX solution since it's more portable and more people at my University could use it.

After reading [LaTeX programming: how to implement conditionals](http://handyfloss.wordpress.com/2007/08/29/latex-programming-how-to-implement-conditionals/) I thought that it might be possible and decided to ask my question here since I'm only 4 days old in the world of LaTeX.

I also read "[How to form "if ... or ... then" conditionals in TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29905/how-to-form-if-or-then-conditionals-in-tex)" and "[LaTeX conditional expression](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/latex-conditional-expression)", but I'm not sure if parsing for a string is supported.

I imagine the scipt to work like:

> **IF** a string called `\label{table_}` is found between `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}`  **THEN** replace `{figure}` with
>   `{table}`

I also found [Search & Replace Script for TeXworks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84668/search-replace-script-for-texworks) but maybe it's possible to handle this all on the compile level, so that I don't have to run anything extra and just can start compiling in Sublime Text when I'm done writing.

---

So why would this be cool…

- obviously it's kind of a must-have for people who write in (Multi)Markdown
- a filter would also allow to split all figures further into catogories *(photographies/images, charts, …)*
- other geeky stuff which depends on parsing the content before compiling a pdf.

I'm open for ideas, solutions, links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an implementation using `environ` and `expl3`. With `environ` we absorb the whole environment's contents and with `l3regex` we check whether the environment contains the tokens

```
\label{table_
```

via the regular expression

```
\c{label}\cB.table_
```

Where `\c{<string>}` matches the control sequence with name `<string>` and `\cB.` matches one open brace.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ,xparse,l3regex}

% environ has problems in renewing
% existent environments
\let\figure\relax
\let\endfigure\relax

\NewEnviron{figure}{\CheckForTable}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \pattulus_check:n #1
 {
  \regex_match:nnTF { \c{label}\cB.table_ } { #1 }
   {
    \@float{table}#1\end@float
   }
   {
    \@float{figure}#1\end@float
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \pattulus_check:n { V }
\NewDocumentCommand{\CheckForTable}{}
 {
  \pattulus_check:V \BODY
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
THIS SHOULD BE A TABLE
\caption{This is the caption.}
\label{table_sometable}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
THIS SHOULD BE A FIGURE
\caption{This is the caption.}
\label{figure_somefigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Update March 2019

After several updates of `expl3` and `xparse`, the code can be reduced:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

% use the default placements htp
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{figure}{O{htp} +b}
 {\pattulus_check:nn { #1 } { #2 }}
 {}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \pattulus_check:nn
 {
  \regex_match:nnTF { \c{label}\cB.table_ } { #2 }
   {
    \@float{table}[#1]#2\end@float
   }
   {
    \@float{figure}[#1]#2\end@float
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
THIS SHOULD BE A TABLE
\caption{This is the caption.}
\label{table_sometable}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
THIS SHOULD BE A FIGURE
\caption{This is the caption.}
\label{figure_somefigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works like a charm. Thank you so much. Great to know how to use a regex with LaTeX.